# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_sql'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sqlite

I'm importing a query to a pandas dataframe, then creating a resulting dataframe called `hindex` to import to my database table as shown below:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#access the database created
db = sqlite3.connect('test/publications')

df = pd.read_sql("select AuthorID as ID, citations from publications as p join authors_publications as a on p.ID=a.PaperID order by AuthorID, citations desc", db)

df2 = df.sort(['ID','Citations'],ascending=['Citations','ID'])
groups = df2.groupby('ID')
ind2 = np.array([np.arange(len(g))+1 for g in groups.groups.itervalues()])
df2['newindex'] = np.hstack(ind2)
df2['condition'] = df2['Citations']>=df2['newindex']
hindex = df2.groupby('ID').sum()['condition']

hindex.to_sql('authors_hindex', db, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

I've used to_sql before and it worked. Not sure why it isn't over here. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0748af5dad1d> in <module>()
     43 
     44 print hindex
---> 45 hindex.to_sql('authors_hindex', db, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=True)
     46 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   1813                 return self[name]
   1814             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 1815                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   1816 
   1817     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_sql'
```

Comment: What version pandas do you have as it should've worked even with a Series

Comment: @EdChum I have 0.13.1

Comment: That's an old version I can't remember when it was added to Series, if you can upgrade, the latest stable version is 0.16.0

Comment: @EdChum. Will do that now. Would that explain also why it doesn't add index as a column when I specified index=True?

Comment: That's also possible the SQL side of pandas has been enhanced significantly as have various bug fixes recently

Comment: @EdChum I tried installing the latest version of pandas using sudo apt-get install python-pandas and it told me that I already have the latest version, but when I type pd.__version__ to check the version on ipython notebook, it still tells me it's 0.13.1. What am I doing wrong? I also tried pip, all told me I already have 0.16.0. So I thought maybe it was an ipython notebook issue, and checked that I also have the latest version of that. Any hints what could be the issue, why is it telling me my version is 0.13.1?

Comment: No idea, you could post another question as I'm not familiar with what could be the problem on linux

Comment: The `to_sql` method was only added to Series in 0.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
hindex = df2.groupby('ID').sum()[['condition']]
```

so using a double `[[]]` will return a df

Your original line: `hindex = df2.groupby('ID').sum()['condition']` returned a Series but this does have a [`to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_sql.html#pandas.Series.to_sql) method though so unclear why this failed.